# How to create a button which is going to be used in all forms with different functions?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, interface

As I mentioned in the question, I am trying to create a button and I wanna use this button in all forms.
I checked MDI application but something is wrong with it. I tried to use interface but it worked only the main form not in childform.

Kind Regards

Comment: winform tag added to question sorry :)

Comment: Do you mean re-use the type of button, or the button instance?

Comment: i got two labels in two different forms. when i click to button if i am in the first form the text of label in the first form will be "test", if i am in the second form the text of label in the second form will be "it is second label". different actions in one button...

Comment: @exstremum So .. If you click on the button you want to change two different labels text in two different forms right......?

Comment: @pratapk it depends on which form i am on it.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want different logical action to be performed for the same visual control (the "Button") ?  If so , the just create a user-control to appear how you like , drop it where ever you like , and override the click event to do what ever you like . If you add the control dynamically - that's a different meter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a way: in the button you can call the `DoWork` method of form and you can make `DoWork` as you want in different forms.

in this way you can get the reference of all forms in central form and in the `ButtonClickEvent` you can call `DoWork` method of the forms.

Comment: i want to do it with using Interface. found the solution with using Interface. Solution: Create an ınterface and declare functions in it. If forms get inherit from interface then we make use them in different actions.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @exstremum: you can make an interface and in the interface create `DoWork` method. and use the interface in the forms.